# In-Place Update of Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas. I've built a dataframe where all the values are lists that look like [Year, Datapoint] (e.g. [2013, 37722.322] or [1998, 32323.232). How do I get rid of the year value and just replace the list in each cell in the dataframe with just the float datapoint?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If possible, show the actual dataframe you want to update. Answer will be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
In [16]:

import operator
In [17]:

DF=pd.DataFrame({'Val':[[2013, 37722.322],[1998, 32323.232]]})
In [18]:

print DF
                 Val
0  [2013, 37722.322]
1  [1998, 32323.232]

[2 rows x 1 columns]
In [19]:

DF['Val2']=DF.Val.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)
In [20]:

print DF
                 Val       Val2
0  [2013, 37722.322]  37722.322
1  [1998, 32323.232]  32323.232

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

To do this to all your columns:
`DF.applymap(operator.itemgetter(-1))` per @DSM's suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot @CT Zhu. Quick follow-up: I have a couple hundred columns, so I can't call a column the way you called the column Val. How would I apply the method you suggested on across every column?

Comment: I think `applymap` would be simpler here, e.g. `DF.applymap(lambda x: x[-1])`.

Comment: Hi John, see edit. I thought `DF.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)` should work but actually it won't?

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the quick follow-up, I'll learn more about operator to understand how that worked.

Comment: Hmmm yeah DF.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1) seems to only work on some of the columns, interesting...

Comment: Wanna ask? If you don't I will, :P

Comment: @DSM that makes a lot of sense and is much simpler than the loops I was trying to write, thanks.